# Rspec 3.1 Core outputs entire object on error when using expect syntax

Tags: formatting, output

Given a failing test, for example:

```
 it "disallows unauthenticated access" do
   sign_out @user
   get :index
   expect(response).to_not be_success
 end
```

Upon failure, rspec outputs the ENTIRE OBJECT(very very huge error output) instead of just the object name.

For example:

```
         disallows unauthenticated access
           Failure/Error: expect(response).to_not be_success
             expected `#<ActionController::TestResponse:0x0000010d18b218  
              ...
              ...
              ... (Goes on forever and ever and ever)
```

Any help from a kind soul would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!